# AWS SDK for java 1.7

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am trying to access a aws webservice here I have lambda expression, but my project is in java 7, So I want to convert this code to normal method.

```
   final Unmarshaller<ApiGatewayResponse, JsonUnmarshallerContext> responseUnmarshaller = in -> {
            System.out.println(in.getHttpResponse());
            return new ApiGatewayResponse(in.getHttpResponse());};
```

Comment: It should be straightforward to translate that.  What have you tried?

Comment: @StephenC Thanks, I am new to lambda, I am trying to initialize `JsonUnmarshallerContext` but this an abstract class, So I have created a custom class to extent the JsonUnmarshallerContext. Still it returns null object
 

JsonUnmarshallerInstianter jsonUnmarshallerContext = new JsonUnmarshallerInstianter();
        final Unmarshaller<ApiGatewayResponse, JsonUnmarshallerContext> responseUnmarshaller = (Unmarshaller<ApiGatewayResponse, JsonUnmarshallerContext>) new ApiGatewayResponse(jsonUnmarshallerContext.getHttpResponse());

Comment: And ... did it work?

Comment: My point is that if you ask someone else to write code for you, you don't learn how to do it for yourself.  If you want resources to learn about lambdas, start with the Oracle Java Tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @StephenC no it didn't worked, am I missing anything here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda expression can be translated into either an anonymous class or a named class.

In your example, you need a class that implements the interface:

```
Unmarshaller<ApiGatewayResponse, JsonUnmarshallerContext>
```

If we look at that [javadocs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0/software/amazon/awssdk/core/runtime/transform/Unmarshaller.html), we see that `com.amazonaws.transform.Unmarshaller` is defined as follows:

```
public interface Unmarshaller<T, R> {
    public T unmarshall(R in) throws Exception;
}
```

So we can create anonymous class + instance as follows:

```
Unmarshaller<ApiGatewayResponse, JsonUnmarshallerContext> responseUnmarshaller =
    new Unmarshaller<>() {
        public ApiGatewayResponse unmarshall(JsonUnmarshallerContext in) 
            throws Exception {
            return ...
        }
};
```

And the body of the `unmarshall` method is simply this:

```
            System.out.println(in.getHttpResponse());
            return new ApiGatewayResponse(in.getHttpResponse());
```

---

Note that there is something fishy about your example.  According to the [javadoc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/apigateway/model/ApiGatewayResponse.html) I am looking at `ApiGatewayResponse` is an abstract class, so we can't `new` it.  But the lambda you are translating (apparently) does.

---

Reference:

- [The Java™ Tutorials > Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it worked. Will look into the doc.